# Не срабатывает функция при загрузке таблицы

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Есть скрипт, в нём функция чтения из текстового файла, который на Google диске. Вся загвоздка в том, что когда запускаешь её из самого редактора или повесить её на какой нибудь пункт меню, всё срабатывает и файл читается, но когда открываешь или обновляешь таблицу, то функция не работает. Собственно нужно, что бы она срабатывала, только когда открываешь таблицу.

```
function onOpen() {
  var fileID = <ID>;
  var fileBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob();
  var values = fileBlob.getDataAsString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ заключается в [Ограничениях](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=ru#restrictions), точнее:

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.

Что значит, что простые триггеры ( как ваш onOpen ) не могут использоваться сервисы, которые требуют авторизацию ( `DriveApp.getFileById(fileID)` потребует авторизацию)

Вместо этого попробуйте [Устанавливаемые триггеры](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=ru), у них функционал шире:

> ...Installable triggers, however, offer more flexibility than simple triggers: they can call services that require authorization...

То есть они способны вызывать сервисы, требующие авторизацию

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло, но странное конечно решение google, пришлось ставить триггер на запуск функции, а потом удалять его же.